# How to put value to the input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to insert the element taken from the "iti__selected-dial-code" class as a value into the tag. I did this for the

tag but I have a problem with the  tag.

My input tag:
`<input type="tel" id="phone" class="tell" name="telephone" value="">`

And js code:

```
var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
    separateDialCode: true,
    utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.8/build/js/utils.js",
});

window.iti = iti;
var code = document.getElementsByClassName("iti__selected-dial-code").item(0).innerHTML;


//It works for <p> tag.

var prefix = document.getElementById("prefix");
prefix.innerText = code;

//I would like it to work as above, so that the prefix moves to the input instead of a <p>.

var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone");
phoneNumber.innerText = code;
```

To make the problem easier to understand, I created a codepen: https://codepen.io/hubu999/pen/qBaOrjL

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("iti__selected-dial-code").item(0);

var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone");
phoneNumber.value = elem.innerHTML;

observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
    console.log(mutationsList);
  phoneNumber.value = elem.innerHTML;
});

// call `observe` on that MutationObserver instance, 
// passing it the element to observe, and the options object
observer.observe(elem, {characterData: true, childList: true, attributes: false});
```

Please see this: [MutationObserver.observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe)

Comment: It looks like the value is being put in but immediately overwritten. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I can't really tell, you should post your full code

Comment: @Hubu999 see my new edit, I found the hidden black magic

Comment: Thank you but I used your code in mine (see codepen) and in the input field I have "[object HTMLDivElement]" instead of "+1".

Comment: I pasted your new code into my codepen and now I have nothing in the input field :(

Comment: @Hubu999 change childList to true. see my new edit

Comment: Its almost perfect! But if I select a country, the prefix goes to the input but I can't enter the number further because it is automatically deleted. Do you know why?